# error C++: cannot convert ‘ '::Vector<double>’ to ‘double’ in assignment sum_aux=A[f][j]*xk[j];

Tags: c++, double

Buenas! Estoy teniendo problemas con el error expuesto cuando intento multiplicar la matriz A con el vector xk. La matriz A la cojo de un fichero externo de entrada. ¿Alguien sabría decirme cómo arreglarlo?. Muchas gracias por adelantado!
Adjunto las partes del código interesantes:

```
Matrix <double> A,B,C;

Vector <double> xk[9] = {27.0000, -0.000901816789824, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, -0.000901816789824 , 0};

int f,j,n, m, p,a,b,b2,c,tam;

double sum_aux=0;
```

```
a = 9;
A.resize(a, a);

//Para matriz A
{
    getline(myfile, line);      
    std::istringstream is(line);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            is >> A[i][j] >> ch;
}
```

```
for(f=1;f<=a;f++){
    sum_aux=0;
    for(j=1;j<=a;j++){
        sum_aux=(double)A[f][j]*xk[j];
        sum_aux=sum_aux + (double)A[f][j+1]*xk[j+1];
    }
    xk_aux[j]=sum_aux;
}
```

Comment: Hola, este es Stack Overflow en **Español**, por favor, por tanto las preguntas aqui planteadas deben estar escritas en esta lengua. Traduce tu pregunta para que nos sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: No es necesario reformularla, solo haz click en _Editar_ y la podras corregir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás podrías probar con ejemplos sencillos. También puedes probar a hacer los accesos con las funciones de la librería vector en C++, por ejemplo la función "at". Prueba un codigo parecido al siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> xk(9);
    xk.resize(9);
    xk.at(0)=27;
    xk.at(1)=0;
    xk.at(2)=0;
    xk.at(3)=0;
    xk.at(4)=0;
    xk.at(5)=0;
    xk.at(6)=0;
    xk.at(7)=0;
    xk.at(8)=0;

    /* Ejemplo de multiplicación. */
    double res = 0.0;

    res = 2*xk.at(0);

    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Saludos!